# How to obtain all "keys" in a NamedNodeMap?

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I use a DOM Parser to parse an XML file. Example code is below:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(inFile);

NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
Node node = nodeList.item(0);

if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
}
```

As documented in the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap.html), the methods `getNamedItem()`, `getNamedItemNS()`
expect the "key" as an input argument, which can then be used to obtain the "value" using [`getNodeValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue%28%29).

However, this expects me to already know the "key" I am looking for. I want to instead obtain the list of "keys" which this NamedNodeMap holds. For example, for the below XML line:

```
<row Id="1" UserId="1" Name="Organizer" Date="2009-07-15T06:51:46.370" />
```

I want to obtain a `List<String>` having `"Id", "UserId", "Name", "Date"`.

The NamedNodeMap has this information, as the screenshot shows, but I cannot figure out how I can obtain this information. Is it possible to do this?

[image: NamedNodeMap contents in debugger]

Answer (score 0):

Just call `NamedNodeMap.item()` and it'll return the attribute node by index (which runs from 0 to `getLength() - 1`)

Comment: getLength() gives the number of "rows" in the XML document, not the attributes within each row. Sorry, I don't know the correct XML terminology, but I hope it is clear what I mean.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I get what you mean. Let me try it out, and confirm if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your original question, you can get the list of keys in `nodeMap` like this:

```js
let keys = [... nodeMap].map((item) => item.name)
```